# Rails MySQL subquery with arithmetic

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, math, count, subquery

I have 3 models:

1. Product
2. Daily Log
3. Click

The tables look like:

```
Products
id
```

,

```
Daily Logs
id | product_id | price
```

,

```
Clicks
id | product_id | daily_log_id
```

For reporting, I would like to get all products that have accrued more than x cost (based on price per click).

In Ruby, the code might look like

```
products.select do | p |
  cost = 0
  p.daily_logs.each do | dlog |
    cost += dlog.clicks.count * dlog.price
  end

  cost > x ? true : false      
end
```

How might I write a similar query for mysql?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT dl.product_id AS `product_id`, COUNT(c.id) AS `total_clicks`, SUM(dl.price) AS `total_price`
FROM daily_logs AS dl
INNER JOIN clicks AS c on dl.id = c.daily_log_id
WHERE `total_price` > ?
GROUP BY `product_id`
```

Note I didn't join the products table as it only has an id field, which is available in the daily_logs table as well. If the products table actually has more fields with information that you need, you could join that table as well and select the needed fields.

Comment: hmm...it doesn't seem to return any results.  How does total_clicks factor in to total_price?

Comment: The total_clicks doesn't calculate into total_price at all, I just figured you might want that value as well. Are you getting some SQL error, or just an empty result set?